# How to decrypt hashed password using php?

Tags: php

I'm currently using MD5 and SHA1 to save my users' passwords in a database but I don't know how to get them back in plain text. I tried to roll back same code I used to encrypt passwords but it gives me an error.

Code I'm using to encrypt passwords:

```
   $hashedpassword = md5(md5(sha1(sha1(md5($normalpassword)))));
```

I tried to do the same thing back like this

```
   $normalpassword = md5(md5(sha1(sha1(md5($hashedpassword)))));
```

Then I realized it's something funny :( !! Please help me...

Comment: hashes are one way, you can never revert it back, the only way is to use brute force attack !

Comment: You don't secure passwords in that way. That causes too much overhead and may have different results even with the same input.

Comment: @MarkGarcia How on Earth could it have different results?

Comment: thnx...I got it..now i know what to do...

Comment: @Tibor Entropy. One rule on Earth you can't escape.

Comment: Why so many down votes? You ask a question to learn, and that obvoiusly worked here. I can imagine many others googling for something similar.

Comment: @MarkGarcia What you say makes no sense. MD5 and SHA1 are dependent only on their input. Same holds for the composition thereof.

Comment: @Ineentho Because it is not a particularly good question. It indicates that OP implemented something he doesn't understand at all. Had he looked up `md5` and `sha1` functions in documentation, the question would not even be necessary.

Comment: @Mark Garcia - Unfortunately there are **not many different results**, because no salt was used! It's important to use a separate salt for each password, and one should use a slow hash function like [bcrypt](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_bcrypt).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MD5 and SHA-1 are one-way hash functions, meaning you can't get back an original string from a hash value.

Comment: OK..I got it ! so i need to hash user password every time they logging and check whethr user entered hashed password is matching with the one in the database...oky thanks..

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Hashing is one way, you'll have to generate a new hash of the input at the login form and check if it is equal to the stored hash.

Answer (score 4):

Hashing ain't encrypting.

A hash function like MD5 and SHA1 can't be reversed, it only can be verifyed. That is usually the point for using a hash function, because the attacker cannot retrieve the clear passwords with the hashes (other attacks, like using rainbow-tables are ofc possible).

More details can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

If you want to store hashed passwords in databases, take a look at [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). It is a good class for php to hash and verify passwords as good as currently possible and is widely used in modern php based web applications.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even encrypting them if you eventually want them back? Hashing is used precisely for the reason of being UNABLE to get passwords back in plaintext.

Use a symmetric cypher if you want them back.

Comment: I'm designing a Facebook Connect logging system for my script so I can't changed original code for password encrypting..My idea was to retrieve them back and do something... anyway thnx..